# How to strace `recvfrom` using `-e`?

Tags: debugging, strace

Debugging a multi-threaded program that does sockets operations mostly, I tried to restrict an `strace` to `recvfrom` and `sendto`.
If I just specify `-f` and `-p <pid>` parameters, I see (among others) `recvfrom` and `sendto` syscalls.

However when I use additional `-e recvfrom -e sendto`, I only see `sendto` syscalls.
I'm using strace 4.10 (strace-4.10-3.1.x86_64 from SLES12 SP4).
Is it a known bug maybe? The syntax says `[-eexpr]...`, so multiple `-e`s should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last `-e` wins, so you have to specify `-e recvfrom,sendto` to trace both syscalls.

Comment: So this means the manual page's syntax is wrong? `[-eexpr]...` is not the same as `[-eexpr[,expr]...]`.

Comment: It's not wrong because `recvfrom,sendto` represents a single expression (=`trace=recvfrom,sendto`).